# Is there a way to add custom icons to a ribbon using VBA through a callback to the UI Editor?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I am making a ribbon for my office. I have programmed all the macros already, except for the icons.
In the UI Editor, I have set everything to be done via a callback in VBA.

I have loaded all the icons using the MS Excel stock icons, however I have 9 icons that have to be added as they are not part of the excel standards.

I can't use different icons as the buttons in the ribbon paste the pictures that I need to display as the icons.

In the UI editor, I have set it up that all the buttons use "getimage=getimage" and have programmed a callback in VBA.

I don't seem to be able to change the 9 specific buttons to "image=pic1" and use the icons (pic1-pic9) I have loaded in the UI Editor. 
When I try to do that, I get an error saying "the 'Image' attribute is not declared"

So now I am looking for a workaround in VBA.

Current callback code for a standard Icon:

Case "eButton03": RibbonImage = "ObjectPictureFill"

I need the code above to pull in a picture instead of using the standard icon.
let's say the picture is saved in C:\Pic\Pic1.png

Comment: `image` is a valid attribute for a button. How and where are you using it?

Comment: I think it might be because I am using getimage for other buttons. Microsoft help says that the two are mutually exclusive, though I am not sure if that applies to a particular line, or if it applies to the entire code.

Comment: <button id="eButton03" getLabel="GetLabel" onAction="RunMacro"  getImage="GetImage" getSize="GetSize" getScreentip = "GetScreentip" getVisible = "GetVisible"/>

|| 

<button id="eButton04" getLabel="GetLabel" onAction="RunMacro"  Image="B1" getSize="GetSize" getScreentip = "GetScreentip" getVisible = "GetVisible"/>

The top line is my standard, the bottom line is the one that gets the error.

Comment: (sorry about the formatting, it won't allow me to neaten it up)

Comment: I use this handy little program for creating my custom ribbons

https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm

I use this website for quick and easy Icons

https://iconsflow.com/dashboard

Comment: Protip: put the relevant code/markup in the post itself, not in comments underneath. See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting.

Comment: It's `image` not `Image`.

Comment: That fixed it. can't believe case was the issue... thanks so much! @Rory

Comment: yeah - XML is case-sensitive! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this list: https://bert-toolkit.com/imagemso-list.html
You can also use or create custom images,  add your picture "yourpic.png" via Excel's "Insert Icons" option in the Custom UI Editor.
Use the code

```
image="yourpic"
```

To use your picture as a custom icon.